# How to optimize a for loop to fill a data frame R

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, dataframe

I have a data frame where I compute a distance matrix.

```
bb=data.frame(Name=paste0('row',1:10),col1=rnorm(10),col2=2*rnorm(10),col3=5*rnorm(10))
dis <- dist(bb[1:nrow(bb),3:ncol(bb)], method = "euclidean")
```

From the computed distance matrix, I create a list showing the distance between every point.

```
library(reshape2)
df=melt(as.matrix(dis), varnames = c("row", "col"))
```

From this, I make a loop to extract the comparison of each point, and normalize based on the values. I then fill a data frame so I get all of them in a single source.

```
s=NULL
for(i in 1:10){
  w=df[df$row==i&df$col!=i,]
  w=w[order(w$value),]
  w[,3]=(w[,3]-min(w[,3]))/(max(w[,3])-min(w[,3])) # there are a few other computations as well, but not included here for simplicity
  s=rbind(s,w)
}
```

At the end, I want to be able to have a single table which can be used in another program which has this format.

```
> head(s,10)
   row col      value
71   1   8 0.00000000
61   1   7 0.08982679
41   1   5 0.25082060
31   1   4 0.42078163
11   1   2 0.53509305
21   1   3 0.61867437
51   1   6 0.67420271
81   1   9 0.69711889
91   1  10 1.00000000
22   2   3 0.00000000
```

My real data has 3K rows and 1.2k columns, and processing time is very slow. Is there a more efficient way of performing a calculation on certain subsets of the dataframe, df, such that I end up with the same at the end.

I have heard that for loops should not be used to grow a data frame, so am curious if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: *"I have heard that for loops should not be used to grow a data frame"*: it's more like [you shouldn't grow a `data.frame` (or any other object) at all](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#chapter.2). Create your object with final size and fill it (with a loop if you want)

Comment: You can predefine your dataframe with `s <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = x, ncol = y))`, where `x` and `y` are your expected dimensions.

Comment: just for closure, I did some benchmarking. My way above: 23.2s, @Cath et al suggestion: 6.0s

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better start thinking in *vectorized mode*.
What you are doing is performing an operation on every row that involves other values on the same row, or simple aggregates like `max` and `min`.

The packages `dplyr` or `data.table` help you doing so.

---

With `dplyr`:

```
# Take only the rows where col is different from row
df <- filter(.data = df, row != col)

# Group by the col variable, usedto isolate each group
df <- group_by(.data = df, col)

# Create a new var 'value2' with the result of the operation
# Note that min and max refers only to the specific group
df <- mutate(.data = df, value2 = (value-min(value))/(max(value) - min(value)))
```

What is nice with `dplyr` is that you can concatenate these steps using `%>%`, where the first argument(`.data`) of the next function is the result of the last operation:

```
df %>% 
    filter(row != col) %>% 
    group_by(col) %>% 
    mutate(value2 = (value-min(value))/(max(value) - min(value)))
```

---

With `data.table`:

```
df <- data.table(df)
df[row!=col, .(value2 = (value-min(value))/(max(value) - min(value))), by=col]
```

[Pls note I'm not that good with `data.table`, there may be better ways to do it]